# How do I hide column in google sheets using APIs?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, googlesheets4

In my project we generate a google sheet with certain number of columns. One of the column, is not important to the user, so I want to hide it for them.

I considered not even generating the column but then that column is important for debugging purposes.

I checked the google APIs doc but couldn't find anything.
Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Reffered to this doc but couldn't find any answer https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to hide a column on a sheet in a Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Sheets API.

In this case, it is required to use [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate). The sample request body is as follows.

#### Sample request body:

In this request body, columns "B" and "D" of `sheetId` are hidden. In this case, the gridrange is used. At that time, the first index is `0`. Please be careful about this.

When you use this request body, please modify the values of `sheetId`, `startIndex`, and `endIndex`.

```json
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateDimensionProperties": {
        "properties": {
          "hiddenByUser": true
        },
        "range": {
          "sheetId": 0,
          "startIndex": 1,
          "endIndex": 2,
          "dimension": "COLUMNS"
        },
        "fields": "hiddenByUser"
      }
    },
    {
      "updateDimensionProperties": {
        "properties": {
          "hiddenByUser": true
        },
        "range": {
          "sheetId": 0,
          "startIndex": 3,
          "endIndex": 4,
          "dimension": "COLUMNS"
        },
        "fields": "hiddenByUser"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For example, when you test this request body, please copy and paste the above request body to "APIs Explorer" of [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate). And, when you set your Spreadsheet ID and "Execute" button, you can see the result in your Spreadsheet.

#### Sample curl command:

The sample curl command is as follows.

```bash
curl --request POST \
  'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[SPREADSHEET_ID]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"requests":[{"updateDimensionProperties":{"properties":{"hiddenByUser":true},"range":{"sheetId":0,"startIndex":1,"endIndex":2,"dimension":"COLUMNS"},"fields":"hiddenByUser"}},{"updateDimensionProperties":{"properties":{"hiddenByUser":true},"range":{"sheetId":0,"startIndex":3,"endIndex":4,"dimension":"COLUMNS"},"fields":"hiddenByUser"}}]}' \
  --compressed
```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatedimensionpropertiesrequest)

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use google-sheets-api to hide a column.
Try this code:

```
// TODO: Replace the column index with your own.
  var COLUMN_INDEX = 1; 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.hideColumns(COLUMN_INDEX);
```